# What is a Shy Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Shy Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

[image: Shy Words]

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Error: 405 Method Not Allowed
```

Comment: Best CSV version ever.

Comment: Gotta love how the comment has more upvotes than the Q and the A

Comment: Great puzzle. Thx!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

A Shy Word™ is a word ...

> ... whose letters nestle, so that a part of a letter is tucked up beneath a part of the other letter.
>
>  This is most obvious when the sloped stems of the A go under the stems of a V or W, but can still be seen when the right part of the L goes under the curve of a U or an O. Also note how no letters of Shy Words™ have vertical stems except at the beginning or at the end.
>
>  This is known as [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) in typography, where some letter pairs have a smaller gap than usual in order to avoid unaesthetic gaps.

There is no CSV version, because ...

> ... kerning depends on the visual representation and therefore on the font. In earlier instances of the "What is a Word" puzzles, a typewriter font was used for the CSV. Monospaced or typewriter fonts don't have kerning; all letters have the same width in such fonts.

Comment: How does this explain PAT being shy, and PATH being unshy?

Comment: And CLAW being unshy?

Comment: @Sconibulus: Because all letter pairs must be kerned: TH, CL and LA aren't. (Maybe they are technically, because they are moved closer to each other to reduce the visual space, but none of them undercuts the other.)

Comment: +1 for mentioning kerning instead of just "squishing the letters together"

Comment: @EngineerToast: Thanks! That's how I noticed the pattern: The Postscript and PDF references use the all-uppercase AWAY to explain kerning.

Comment: Kerning is actually more general. *Increasing* the space between certain letter pairs (or triples) is also kerning (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning#Kerning_values).

Comment: @LarsH: yes, I know. That's why I said in my comment that CL and LA are probably "technically" kerned, i.e. in the sense that kerning is a gap adjustment between individual letters. (I probably don't make that clear in the post itself, though. It's hard to find a good line between description and technical accuracy here. If I hadn't mentioned kerning someone would probably have commented: "FYI, That's called kerning!")

Comment: You could say that a "shy" word is a word in which all the pairs of adjacent letters are *negatively* kerned (again, following the wikipedia article). But yes that is getting technical.

Comment: @Rand al'Thor CLAW is not shy, because the A is only underneath part of the W on the right; all the other shy words have a left-and-right-side coverage.

Answer (score 8):

What I can conclude from the given dataset is that

> There has to be at least one perfectly vertical line on either side of the space between the letters in order for a word not to be shy. If that perfectly vertical line is absent, we can call that word "shy".

OK. Let me clarify my answer a bit.
Here are the rules.

> 1. Letters having a perfectly vertical line are letters like B, D, K etc. (on the left), and H, M, N etc. (on both the sides). Note that there is no letter having a perfectly vertical line only on the right.
> 2. Let us name them P-L (ones with only towards the left) and P-B (having on both the sides) letters.
> 3. Now if the word has atleast one P-B letter, it is not shy.
> 4. And if the word has 2 P-L letters, it is not shy.
> 5. And the words having only one P-L letter must have it anywhere but in the first position.
> 6. All the rest of the words would be shy.

Comment: How does this prove that CLAW (watch the L, no perfect vertical line there) is non-shy™?

Comment: L has a perfect vertical line for the space before

Comment: I mean, the C doesn't though, and the A doesn't. Please be more clear; what I understand is that the letter before and the letter after must have at least 1 vertical line. Also, L A does not have a vertical line between the two letters if you mean that. (space after)

Comment: Not exactly, only one direction (either left or right) would suffice to be not shy

Comment: Also, I am new to this site so please bear with my editing skills

Comment: Thanks for clarification! +1'd this. I will suggest an edit to improve the format.

Comment: Thanks for the one up. I am still learning to provide solutions with detailed explanations.

Answer (score 6):

> In a "shy" word no letters touch a surrounding letter's nearest ends:
>
> For example in a shy word like "AVOW" all ends point away from the other letters' ends, whereas in the non-shy word "SWEAR" the "E" and "A" touch at the bottom, as well as the "A" and "R"
>
>  **Edit:** To make it clearer, you can think of the ends as a letter's "hands". **A** has two hands on the bottom, **L** has two hands on the top and bottom, **W** has two hands on the top. **T** also has only two hands on the top, because those are the ends that can "reach out" to its surrounding letters.
>
> So "shy" words are words that don't hold hands.

Comment: I like your lateral thinking. So according to this theory, letters like "BUT" and "EAT" are not shy and "DOUBT" is shy... please help here, its making me "CRAZY"(again not shy)

Comment: Yes, that's what I think ^^